# Graph "ErrorApiQuarantined"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

When calling `/v1.0/me/calendarview?startdatetime=2019-10-07T12:17:48.964Z&enddatetime=2019-10-14T12:17:48.964Z` in Microsoft Graph, I receive the following error :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorApiQuarantined",
    "message": "Request has been quarantined by condition.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "ca5247f8-b461-4270-89e5-186ed6a3b8fe",
      "date": "2019-10-07T12:17:49"
    }
  }
}
```

I also receive the same error when calling `/v1.0/me/messages`. It looks like all the Outlook APIs aren't working anymore.

Comment: When did this start happening?

Comment: Is your subscription expired?

Comment: I've only seen this occur in cases where the tenant/exchange has been hammered beyond the point of throttling (i.e. found one example where the mailbox was getting 15k+ requests per second). I would start by looking at the health of your tenant @ https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/servicehealth

Comment: This appears to be happening to others, e.g. [here on the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b6639957-c56a-458c-a1fa-a41b8f9d73e5/ms-graph-subscription-not-working?forum=outlookdev).

Comment: This start happening this week. It's on a developer tenant that is still valid. Also on the company tenant It happend

Comment: The tenant health is all green and healthy

Comment: same for me on the /me/events and also the me/messages endpoint if I use the graph-explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#

{
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorApiQuarantined",
    "message": "Request has been quarantined by condition.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "f973714f-98f4-495e-a543-a0b47b649fdf",
        "date": "2019-10-07T13:48:37"
    }
}
}
When I call the API from my SPFx webpart with the MSGraphClient, I get all the events back.

Comment: I'm getting this error message too, for things that worked last time I checked a week or so ago.

Comment: Same as @finisterre. Worked fine last time I checked, quarantined for a simple /me/events. I guess we're waiting for microsoft to fix the bug ...

Comment: Same here. Everything was working until this morning. No changes whatsoever.

Comment: I'm getting this error also

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to OP's question per se, as I'm pretty sure the problem is over on Microsoft's end and there's little we can do for requests that worked perfectly fine recently, but it's some sort of a solution for now.

If you have some code that can run your requests use that instead of the Graph. My code that does various graph requests is still working fine, despite the actual graph explorer quarantineing every little thing.
Using code samples like [this C# solution](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) can keep you going for the time being

I'll delete this as soon as a proper answer is posted later on.

Answer (score 0):

In talking to engineering. This error actually occurs when you have used too many openTypeExtensions on items in the users mailbox. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0

You should look at how many openTypeExtensions are you using right now in your solution? or other solutions that the user mailbox has added?