# MS Graph Mail Subscription notification not working

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I tried to create a MS Graph Mail Subscription through Graph Explorer as given below . This was working fine till 1 week back perfectly.

```
{

"changeType": "created",
"notificationUrl": "https://glowhookfunction.azurewebsites.net/api/ProcessMail",
"resource": "me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
"expirationDateTime":"2019-10-09T18:23:45.9356913Z"
}
```

and I getting the error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ExtensionError",
        "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: InternalServerError; Reason: Request has been quarantined by condition.]",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "65ee6fd6-dd28-4348-bead-c3316c1ea1fb",
            "date": "2019-10-07T11:09:05"
        }
    }
}
```

This was working fine till last week. The notification is sending to an Azure function. I validating the "validationToken" and sends it back as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a bug on the Microsoft side. Looks like others are reporting issues as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58269461/graph-errorapiquarantined

Answer (score 1):

This is the same question as [Graph "ErrorApiQuarantined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58269461/graph-errorapiquarantined/58961690#58961690)

In talking to engineering. This error actually occurs when you have used too many openTypeExtensions on items in the users mailbox. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0

You should look at how many openTypeExtensions are you using right now in your solution? or other solutions that the user mailbox has added?